# Return combination of variable and string in perl

Tags: git, perl, curl

I have a Module that reads from the config file. It fetches and stores the values from the config file into $path, $file, $host. When I pass these values into a new subroutine and concatinate with a string and try to return it, it fails. Gives me an error:

**Module :**

```
package Module;

use strict;
use Carp;

# Constructor and initialisation 
sub new {                               #class method
    my $class = shift;              #shift without arguments is shift @_ , takes 1st element of argument array
    my $self = {};          #created a Hash reference with @_ helping to store values in a hash
    bless ($self, $class);          #turning self into an object by telling which class it belongs to without hardcode name in
    $self->{_created} = 1; #syntax for accessing the contemts of a hash: refrence $object_name->{property_name}.
    return $self;
}

 #reading from config file
 sub read {
    my ($self, $file) = @_;
    my ($line, $section);
    open(HFILE, "$file") || die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
    $self->{_filename} = $file;     # Store a special property containing the name of the file

    while (chomp (my $line = <HFILE>))
    {
            if ($line =~ /^\[(.*)\]/)
            {
                    $section = $1;
            }
            elsif ($line =~ /^([^=]+)=(.*)/)
            {
                    my ($config_name, $config_val) = ($1, $2);
                    if ($section)
                            {
                                    $self->{"$section.$config_name"} = $config_val;
                            } else {
                                    $self->{$config_name} = $config_val;
                                    }
            }
    }

    close HFILE;
    return 1;
    }



#fetching values needed
sub fetch {
    my ($self, $key) = @_;
    return $self->{$key};
}

sub _setup{
    my ($self, @location) = @_;
    my $command = ''.$location[1].' --eg-config '.$location[0].' -H "Host:'.$location[2].'" -ik https://'.$location[2].'';
    return $self->$command;
}
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Module;
use strict;

my $value = Module->new();

$value->read("/Users/hhansraj/git/edgegrid-curl/api.txt") or die "Couldn't read config file: $!";
my $path=$value->fetch('location.path');
my $file=$value->fetch('location.file');
my $host=$value->fetch('credentials.host');
$value->_setup($path,$file,$host);
```

Comment: DELETE YOUR CREDENTIALS! Never expose secrets in a question.

Comment: sschale wasn't clear enough. You need to *change* your credentials, because they're still in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36144126/revisions) and the original version of your question has almost certainly already been cached by search engines and copycat sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are reading an `INI` file, I would strongly recommend to use a Config module like: [Config::ZOMG](http://p3rl.org/Config::ZOMG) or [Config::INI](http://p3rl.org/Config::INI)

The latter should be simple:

```
my $config = Config::INI::Reader->read_file('config.ini');
print $config->{location}->{file};
```

With a proper OO like Moo your code would be:

**MyClass.pm:**

```
package MyClass;

use Config::INI::Reader;

use Moo;

has 'config_file' => (is => 'ro',   required => 1);
has 'config'      => (is => 'lazy', default => sub { Config::INI::Reader->read_file(shift->config_file); });

sub setup {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $path = $self->config->{location}->{path};
    my $file = $self->config->{location}->{file};
    my $host = $self->config->{credentials}->{host};

    return sprintf "%s --eg-config '%s' -H 'Host: %s' -ik https://%s", ($file, $path, $host, $host); 
}
```

**script:**

```
use MyClass;

my $mc = MyClass->new( config_file => 'config.ini');
$mc->setup();
```

Anyway, the actual problem with your file is that you are trying to call a method on $self named after the contents of `$command`. Perhaps you just wanted to return the $command variable in the `_setup` method?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are wanting the **_setup** method to actually execute the command.  Your best bet for that is [system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  To use "system", you need to check the return value is 0.  From the previously linked documentation:

```
Since "SIGINT" and "SIGQUIT" are ignored during the execution
of "system", if you expect your program to terminate on receipt
of these signals you will need to arrange to do so yourself
based on the return value.

   @args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
   system(@args) == 0
       or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

Before you do that though, I highly recommend you verify that the final command string is exactly the way you want it by printing it to standard out first.  And since this is part of a config/setup module, you may as well add another config option called "testing" or something similar.  Then, when **_setup()** is called, it can either print the command or execute it depending on the value of "testing".

If the return value is non-zero, something has gone wrong and you might as well **die()** there and then.  However, once you've ironed out bugs and got it going, the command failures are usually going to be caused by bad configuration values supplied by the module user - so, you should use [croak() from the Carp module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) (I notice you're already using the module).  This will highlight the failure from the callers perspective rather than your module's perspective.

Putting this togeather gives us something like:

```
    ... as above ...
    bless ($self, $class);       #turning self into an object by telling which ...
    $self->{_created} = 1;       #syntax for accessing the contemts of a hash: ...
    $self->{_testing} = 0        # Initialize new config option
    return $self;
}
... etc ...

sub _setup{
    my ($self, @location) = @_;
    my $command = sprintf("%s --eg-config '%s' -H 'Host: %s' -ik https://%s",
                          @location[1,0,2,2]);
    if $self->_testing {
        print "Would have executed: $command\n"
    }
    else {
        system($command) == 0 or croak "system $command failed: $?"
    }
}
```